# DevExpress XtraScheduler hanging on adding appointment to Storage

Tags: devexpress

I have a XtraScheduler SchedulerControl configured as the following:

```cs
private DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl _SchedulerControl;
public DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl ConvSchedulerControl
{
    get
    {
        if (_SchedulerControl == null)
        {
            _SchedulerControl = new DevExpress.XtraScheduler.SchedulerControl();

            _SchedulerControl.Storage = new SchedulerStorage();
            _SchedulerControl.Storage.Appointments.Mappings.Subject = "StandingOrderIDString";
            _SchedulerControl.Storage.Appointments.Mappings.Start = "ScheduledDate";
            _SchedulerControl.Storage.Appointments.Mappings.RecurrenceInfo = "RecurrenceInfo";
            _SchedulerControl.Storage.Appointments.Mappings.Type = "Type";

            _SchedulerControl.Storage.Appointments.CustomFieldMappings.Add(new DevExpress.XtraScheduler.AppointmentCustomFieldMapping("Inactive", "Inactive"));
            _SchedulerControl.Storage.Appointments.CustomFieldMappings.Add(new DevExpress.XtraScheduler.AppointmentCustomFieldMapping("StandingOrderKEY", "StandingOrderKEY"));

            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = new List<StandingOrder>();
            _SchedulerControl.Storage.Appointments.DataSource = bs;
        }
        return _SchedulerControl;
    }
}
```

and I am attempting to programmatically add an appointment with recurrence information, as in the examples given at http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument6201 .  However, when the method execution reaches its final line (indicated) that adds the created appointment to the storage, it "hangs."  No exception is ever thrown; I have left it running for upwards of 15 minutes with no change:

```cs
public void SetRecurrence(DateTime startDate, DateTime? endDate)
{
    Appointment appointmentObj = ConvSchedulerControl.Storage.CreateAppointment(AppointmentType.Pattern);

    if (endDate != null &&
        endDate != DateTime.Parse("12/31/2999"))
    {
        appointmentObj.End = (DateTime)endDate;
    }
    else
    {
        appointmentObj.RecurrenceInfo.Range = RecurrenceRange.NoEndDate;
    }

    appointmentObj.Start = startDate;
    appointmentObj.RecurrenceInfo.Type = RecurrenceType.Weekly;
    appointmentObj.RecurrenceInfo.WeekDays = WeekDays.Monday;
    appointmentObj.AllDay = true;

//Program execution reaches this line, but never proceeds past it.
    ConvSchedulerControl.Storage.Appointments.Add(appointmentObj);
}
```

I would imagine that there's something wrong with the configuration that's preventing the storage from being able to successfully add the appointment, but I've been unable to turn up any other information on the subject.  Does anyone know why this method isn't appropriate for adding an appointment to the storage, and how it can be corrected?

Comment: Could it be because you don't have a mapping for 'End'? I believe one is required.

Comment: @kenrogers Adding a mapping for End did indeed solve the problem.  Could you submit this as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?  Also, would you be able to provide me with more info on how you discovered this was a "required" field?  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. See my answer for how I discovered this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've failed to provide a mapping for the 'End' field. This is a required mapping. Honestly, I only know this from having created a calendar in the designer. When you place a SchedulerControl onto a form/control, one of the things the designer gives you is a "Mappings Wizard". The 'Start' and 'End' fields are marked in the wizard as being required.